# Not able to show Google Map in android version 4.1 whereas map is visible in android higher then version 5

Tags: android, google-maps

In this i have alse implemented firebase service of google previously i was not using firebase service so that time my  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0' it was working fine in 4.1 and all the other version of android and now becoz of firebase service i m not able to see map in android 4.1 becoz i have to upgraded the version of google play service to 9.4.0

build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app.beeonline.com.attendance"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the line `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'` because it will add all the Google Play and Firebase libraries to you app. It will also increase the build time and the size of the APK file. So replace it with the library that you only need. Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) for the Google Play libraries. And this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries) for the Firebase libraries.

Lastly, I don't see the library for Google Maps, it seems that you forgot to include it.

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0
```

And make sure your classpath is like this when using Firebase, because sometimes it is the problem.

```
buildscript {
dependencies {
// Add this line
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}
```